# how to add multiple selections to segment controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image: segment controller]

In xcode you can implement a segment controller, but it just allows to select one at the time! 
What is the easiest way to make something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this with UISegmentedControl. What you can do is create some UIButtons and set custom selected state images for them, so you know when they are selected.

Comment: Do you know any resource-sites with segment design?

Comment: I always check for new controls at www.cocoacontrols.com

Answer (score 0):

use [**ATHMultiSelectionSegmentedControl**](https://github.com/attheodo/ATHMultiSelectionSegmentedControl) from Github

[This is the Cocoapod](https://cocoapods.org/?q=lang%3Aswift%20ATHMultiSelectionSegmentedControl)